# Uploading Records from Excel file to Server - Desktop App

Tags: json, sql-server, excel, exe, desktop-application

I have requirements as below :

There is a folder named **BATCH** inside **D://** drive of my PC.

Now this **D://BATCH** contains excel files with any random names. Every excel file has only one record.

I have to create .exe file or any Desktop Application which lets the user to browse the **BATCH** folder and then can upload the content or data from the excel files to our Server. We have to put the excel data into **JSON** and then have to upload it to the server.

One more thing is that If I have uploaded data from 3 files and then again user tries to upload by selecting the folder, data which are new or not uploaded only those data should be upload. The data in BATCH folder is generating daily with connected machine.

My background is for Web and Mobile development. So, little bit confused of achieving this thing as explained above.

So, How can I achieve this? Which technology I have to use or which are the tools that can be useful?

Thanks for the support.

Comment: What language/IDE do you want to develop the desktop app in. Excel as a library that you can use from Visual Studio for example. How are you connecting to the SQL server? This question is too broad for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably a bunch of ways to skin this cat.  Maybe import everything from all Excel files in the folder into one single Excel file, and export this to SQL Server.  Just a thought.

```
Sub InsertInto()

'Declare some variables
Dim cnn As adodb.Connection
Dim cmd As adodb.Command
Dim strSQL As String

'Create a new Connection object
Set cnn = New adodb.Connection

'Set the connection string
cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Data Source=Server_Name"

'Create a new Command object
Set cmd = New adodb.Command

'Open the Connection to the database
cnn.Open

'Associate the command with the connection
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn

'Tell the Command we are giving it a bit of SQL to run, not a stored procedure
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

'Create the SQL
strSQL = "UPDATE TBL SET JOIN_DT = '2019-12-10' WHERE EMPID = 2"

'Pass the SQL to the Command object
cmd.CommandText = strSQL


'Execute the bit of SQL to update the database
cmd.Execute

'Close the connection again
cnn.Close

'Remove the objects
Set cmd = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Just to embellish my original answer a bit...you can easily import data from multiple excel files in a folder, into one single Excel file, using a concept like the one below.

```
Sub Basic_Example_1()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long

    'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
    MyPath = "C:\Users\Ron\test"

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    Fnum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        Fnum = Fnum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
        MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    rnum = 1

    'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
    If Fnum > 0 Then
        For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

                On Error Resume Next

                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    Set sourceRange = .Range("A1:C1")
                End With

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    'if SourceRange use all columns then skip this file
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough rows in the sheet"
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        'Copy the file name in column A
                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                    Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = MyFiles(Fnum)
                        End With

                        'Set the destrange
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                        'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If

        Next Fnum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

See the link below for some ideas of how to get data from several Excel files/sources, consolidate into one single file/source.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win008.htm

Keep an open mind about this kind of stuff.  There are several other ways to do essentially the same kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

The question is too broad and you can achieve your requirement in many ways.

If you consider using `c#` you can develop a `WPF` or `Winforms` Project.

You will need to follow these basic steps

1. A function to browse and pick your file like `FolderBrowserDialog` available in `System.Windows.Forms`. In case you are using WPF you have to add reference to the library
2. Read the excel contents. In this case you may need references to any library/nuget package like `Epplus`, `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`, `LinqToExcel` or `ExcelLibrary`
3. Convert data to json format using `Newtonsoft.Json` nuget package
4. Upload or save data to SQL Server - Here you would need a connection string to the database and save the same in your .config file. you can use ADO, linq to sql etc for that.

Sample Code

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.Filter = "Excel files (*.xls)|*.csv|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog()== DialogResult.OK)
{
       //Open file and read contents

       var excelFile = new LinqToExcel.ExcelQueryFactory(path);


            var query =
                from row in excelFile.Worksheet("Sheet1")
                let item = new
                {
                    Column1 = row["Column1"].Cast<string>(),
                    Column2 = row["Column2"].Cast<int>(),

                }

                select item;

            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                MyCustomClass myClass = new MyCustomClass();
                myClass.Column1 = item.Column1;
                myClass.Column2 = item.Column2;

                //Do something
            }
            //convert to json
            // Save to database
}
```